# superclass operator() error - ambiguous

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguous

I am trying to use C++11 to define a class which can store several `std::function<>` and call them depending on their argument types, similar to overload resolution.

I declare a base class for each function signature the 'overloaded' function should support:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename... A>
struct overload;

template <typename R, typename... A>
struct overload<R(A...)>
{
  typedef std::function<R(A...)> F;
  F f_;
  overload(F f): f_(f) {}
  R operator()(A... a)
  {
    return f_(a...);
  }
};

template <typename... T>
struct overloaded_function : public overload<T>...
{
  overloaded_function(T... t): overload<T>(t)... {}
};

int main()
{
  overloaded_function<void(float), void(int, int)> f([](float){}, [](int, int){});
  f(1.F);  // build error
  f(2, 3); // build error
  return 0;
}
```

Build error: (Visual Studio 2013)

> "overload::operator() [with R=void, A=]" is ambiguous
>   c:\Users\benj7280\Documents\kernel_builder\src\main.cpp   39  5   kernel_builder

I don't understand how the operator can be ambiguous since the functions have totally different signatures. The error was exactly the same when I removed the templates altogether, using only concrete classes, and also when I replaced the `operator()` overload with a named member function.

Comment: Member functions with the same name from different base classes don't overload. You need `using`s.

Comment: ADL to the rescue! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51f94aeb243926ae

Comment: @T.C. That edit might hide a misunderstanding of the OP..

Comment: @dyp Fair enough. I'll just note in the comment that the primary template for `overload` should just have one parameter with no pack.

Comment: @dyp your ADL solution doesn't build for me: "Failed to specialize function template"

Comment: @Kietz VS seems to have some problem with the return type :( (most probably a VS bug). It works when removing the return type: http://rextester.com/JRYFR74138 possibly there's also a work-around for non-void return types.

Comment: @Kietz Workaround: http://rextester.com/JPDXKV81915 Probably related to using `this` in a trailing-return-type, I guess.

Comment: @dyp that worked, thanks! Will you post that as an answer? Also, why didn't this work (there's only a single chain of inheritance): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dcd807a3f9cb69e

Comment: @Kietz That didn't work first of all because there's a semicolon missing ;) and secondly, `operator()` in the every of those classes hides the `operator()` of its base(s). That's why you have to make it visible again with a using-declaration (as in Barry's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the base class `operator()`s with `using`. However, I don't know how to do  that with parameter packs so hopefully somebody else can hop in and answer that.

What I can do is redo your structure so that it inherits linearly all the way up and each overload only needs to `using` the next one:

```
template <typename... T>
struct overloads
{
    // need this one so that the last overload has 
    // something to "using". If you have an overload for void(),
    // that one will hide this one. If you don't, and call f(),
    // this won't compile... which is fine.
    void operator()();
};

template <typename R, typename... A, typename... T>
struct overloads<R(A...), T...>
: overloads<T...>
{
  typedef std::function<R(A...)> F;
  F f_;

  template <typename... Fs>
  overloads(F f, Fs... fs)
  : overloads<T...>(fs...)
  , f_(f)
  {}

  using overloads<T...>::operator();

  R operator()(A... a)
  {
    return f_(a...);
  }
};

template <typename... T>
struct overloaded_function : public overloads<T...>
{
  overloaded_function(T... t)
  : overloads<T...>(t...)
  { }
};
```

And now your `f(1.F)` and `f(2, 3)` calls both compile, since now all the overloads are... overloadable.

Comment: *"However, I don't know how to do that with parameter packs so hopefully somebody else can hop in and answer that."* After looking into the Standard, I think it's just not one of the contexts where pack expansion is allowed..

Comment: @dyp - I guess that's good, because I thought I tried every permutation and would be pretty bummed if there was just that one obscure `...` placement that I missed. But otherwise, d'oh!

Comment: There's an open issue to allow pack expansion in using declarations, so maybe we'll see it in C++17. Also I'd do the inheritance somewhat differently: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c71372782285a884

Comment: @T.C. What's the advantage of one over the other?

Comment: Not needing the awkward `void operator()();`, mostly.

Comment: @T.C. note that `head:tail...` inheritance has a high cost at compile time (Both time and RAM consumption, but that depends on the compiler) since in that way the compiler should instantiate N templates, instead of just expanding a pack. You should prefer pack expansion inheritance whenever possible to reduce compilation times.

Comment: @Manu343726 You have to do it recursively in this case because you can't pack-expand in a `using`.

Comment: @T.C. You don't *have* to derive recursively here; only if you want to use *using-declarations* ;)